# SQL Server: should I use an "Agent Job" or a "Maintenance Plan" to delete old data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plan

I'm looking for a way to periodically (e.g. weekly) run some SQL statements in a database to delete old data. As far as I can see, there are (at least) two ways to do this:

- using a "Maintenance Plan" and a "Execute T-SQL Statement Task"
- using an "SQL Server Agent Job" and specify the statements in a "Step" of that job

My question is: what is the difference between these two possibilities and which one should I use for my task?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not really an either/or choice; there's some overlap.

Think of a Maintenance Plan as a collection of steps to "do something" to your databases; those steps are encapsulated into a plan which needs to be scheduled to run.

The SQL Server Agent is the service that periodically runs jobs; a job is anything that is scheduled to run.  A Maintenance Plan is a job.

When you schedule a Maintenance Plan to run, you are actually creating a job (or jobs; thanks DJ) for the SQL Server Agent to run periodically.

Now, as to choosing which way is best (to go through the Maintenance Plan wizard or directly through the Agent), I would say that for most databases, the Maintenance Plan Wizard is suffecient.  You may want to add additional steps to the job(s) created by the Maintenance Plan, but that depends on your environment.

Does that make sense?

Comment: So the maintenance plan is just a graphical user interface to create SQL server agent jobs, and put them into a specific order?

Comment: not quite; a maintenance plan is a graphical user interface to create a specific type of job.  You can do other things with SQL Server Agent than just Maintenance plans.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant: maintenance plans are a nice GUI allowing you to set up a subset of sql server agent job's functionality. Thanks a lot!

Comment: seems that maintenance plan wizard doesnt warn you if 'sql server agent' isn't running but it is required to run maintenance plan tasks. so make sure agent is running and set to 'automatic' start